# Multiple Linear Regression: Proof of Pythegore's Theorem

Tags: regression, self-study, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression

How can I prove pythegore's theorem?

Where $y'$ is the transpose of $y $

And the $\hat{y}$ matrix is the matrix of the estimated values of $y$.

So far, I have:

$y'\hat{y} = y'y$

$ \implies (X\beta + \epsilon)' (X  (X' X)^{-1} X' y) = (X\beta + \epsilon)' (y)$

$\implies \beta' X' X (X' X)^{-1} X' y + \epsilon ' X (X' X)^{-1} X' y = \beta' X' Y + \epsilon ' y$

$\implies \beta' X' Y + \epsilon ' X (X' X)^{-1} X' y = \beta' X' y + \epsilon' y$

but $\beta' X' Y$ is a $1 \times p$ times $p \times n$ times $n \times 1$ matrix i.e. a $1\times 1$ matrix i.e. a scalar, so I can simply subtract it from both sides, yielding

$\epsilon ' X (X' X)^{-1} X' y = \epsilon' y$

$\implies X (X' X)^{-1} X' =I$

i.e. the Hat matrix $H =I$ for ANY $n \times n$ identity matrix, which is obviously a nonsensical result.

Is this a better, more sound way of disproving this?

Comment: Add the self study tag.

Comment: I've tidied up the mathematical text. Please do make sure it gives your same calculations. You may be able to see the pattern of what I did if you have to edit a typo of mine, but if you don't point me to the correction for me to make it. Write "@Dave" at the beginning of your response so I get an alert that you've replied. I do want to remark about point #2. If you can find $X$ such that $H \ne I$, then you're done (assuming the rest of the calculation is true), yes. However, you don't get to adjust $n$ willy nilly. $n$ is fixed by the number of columns in $X$.

Comment: This is called Pythagore's theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^TAy=x^Ty$ does not force $A=I$, e.g. $y$ can be an eigenvector of $A$ with $\lambda=1$. So, even if you show $H\neq I$, it doesn't prove anything. And, if you intend to go numerically, it's just one step away for you to really find that $y^T\hat{y}\neq y^Ty$.

However, it is true that $\hat{y}'\hat{y}=\hat{y}'y$ because the estimation method assumes that the error is *orthogonal* to the data (I think @Xian's comment is for this one), you can also check it by substitution easily. Maybe you were asking for it.

Note:

> but ′′ is a 1× times × times ×1 matrix i.e. a 1×1 matrix
>   i.e. a scalar, so I can simply subtract it from both sides...

You can always do that. It doesn't have to be a scalar.